# overridePendingTransition doesn't work

Tags: android, animation, transition

Have found already some people asking the same, but the solutions didn't work for me.

I see no animation.

Calling it this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
```

fadein.xml and fadeout.xml are in the anim folder:

fadein.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

fadeout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <alpha
      android:duration="1000"
      android:fromAlpha="1.0"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```

Using min. API 7:

manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

API 7 is also in my project.properties file:

```
target=android-7
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.D. Removing the lines with the interpolator doesn't change anything.

Already seen / tried:

[overridePendingTransition doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364714/overridependingtransition-doesnt-work)

[overridePendingTransition does not work when FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633543/overridependingtransition-does-not-work-when-flag-activity-reorder-to-front-is-u)

[Fade in Activity from previous Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150054/fade-in-activity-from-previous-activity-in-android)

[Fade in Activity from previous Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150054/fade-in-activity-from-previous-activity-in-android)

[Activity transition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android)

Comment: please check this solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633543/overridependingtransition-does-not-work-when-flag-activity-reorder-to-front-is-u

Comment: i codded a basic workadrond :) 
read my ansver http://stackoverflow.com/a/22035320/686463

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was that the device, at least in the case of Samsung Galaxy, has to have animations enabled for this to work. This can be done in the settings menu.

Comment: how to activate animation automatically ?

Answer (score 14):

You need to make sure that you havn't turned it off in the device using the **Settings > Developer Options**:

[image]

you should turn on **Transition animation scale**.

Answer (score 3):

As you said in some Samsung devices (maybe others to) the option "All animations" in Settings->Display->Animation ha to be selected and not the default "Some animations"

Comment: do you know how to activate it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that might be happen to you, for animation doesn't work, it's because your current activity is different from the next activity you intent to. And instead to make the animation he destroy the current activity, and therefor the animation doesn't show, make sure that your both activity's are in the same orientation.