# How can I avoid fade to black on Activity transition?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I am creating an app where almost all of the animations are fades. For a few of the pages, elements will dynamically appear / disappear off the screen, and all the fading is quite natural (white background for the app). However, when I transition between Activities, the app fades to black before fading back into the next Activity. Since all the backgrounds are the same color, I was wondering if there was a way to avoid this, so that the background constantly remains the same color, and only the elements on it seem to fade as the app state changes.

I use the following code for my transitions:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Sometimes without the `finish()`, as necessary. I've looked into this briefly, and the problem other people seem to have is with a long lasting black screen that is associated with `NextActivity` having a computationally intensive `onCreate()`. This is not the case for me. The `onCreate()` methods do little in terms of computing, merely define some listeners. All intense logic is offloaded to threads. It is quite literally a UI problem for me that I am trying to find a work around for.

Comment: Try adding this `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.my_drawable);` before `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);` -- and, of course, make a non-black drawable for it to reference.

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately

Comment: You might try setting either of these, or both, in your styles rather than trying it programatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266221/difference-between-androidwindowbackground-and-androidcolorbackground

Answer (score 2):

I found that setting `android:zAdjustment="top"` on the fade out animation made the black screen in-between go away.

See sample XML in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9150436/1481500

Answer (score 1):

I recommend people looking at this question to check out at **Taig's** answer in this other question. Much simpler solution for people that want a nice fade transition:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34024547/8050896

The gist of it is to **only set a fade-out** animation between the transition to avoid seeing the launcher background when both activities fade. So the second activity doesn't actually have an animation.

```
startActivity( ... );
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.screen_splash_fade_out); // only a fade out animation
```